# Silvery fish with red eyes and neon fins

Tags: aquarium, fish

Please, help me identify this fish.

After going through some local aquarium & pet stores in Chengdu, China, where I am visiting, I was able to identify most of the fishes I saw. Except this one. It has white silvery body with a redish spot on head, partially red eyes and fins which seem to be glowing with blue neon color. The fish is about 1 or 2 inches long.

[image: Silvery fish with red eyes and neon fins]

I guess, this is a relative of the Electric Blue Ram, but I am not sure. I am new to aquarium hobby, so would be thankful for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a gold ram, or some hybrid with an electric blue ram, but the lighting makes it a bit difficult to identify. But, basically the exact same care as German blue rams, but the color is different. Both types have very short lifespans and require very high quality water, similar to discus.